# Decoding Soil Moisture Sensor 433 MHz

Tags: arduino, decoder, 433mhz

I need to decode soil moisture sensor using RXB6 and ESP32. I tried several libraries; it can get data but not the correct one. Due to my knowledge on this 433 MHz radio, I can't figure out.

There's a decoder for it using RTL_SDR,
https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433/blob/master/src/devices/rainpoint.c

**What I know about it:**

It is OOK PCM at 500 µs rate (half-bit rate as it's Manchester)

Detail I get on RTL_433_SDR:

```
time      : 2023-02-14 14:06:54
model     : RainPoint-Soil                         id        : 0603
channel   : 1            Sync?     : aa81          Flags?    : 9f            Status?   : 0402          Temperature: 32.0 C       Moisture  : 7 %           Integrity : CHECKSUM
pulse_slicer_pcm(): RainPoint soil temperature and moisture sensor
bitbuffer:: Number of rows: 1 
[00] {2780} 55 55 55 54 cc cd 2a ac d2 ab 4a ab 55 2c b2 aa ca aa aa cb 52 aa aa ab 34 b3 33 2a ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff da aa aa aa a6 66 69 55 66 95 5a 55 5a a9 65 95 56 55 55 56 5a 95 55 55 59 a5 99 99 57 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff fe d5 55 55 55 33 33 4a ab 34 aa d2 aa d5 4b 2c aa b2 aa aa b2 d4 aa aa aa cd 2c cc ca 80
```

I have tried the following library which give me data but not correct one:
https://github.com/robwlakes/433MHz_Tx_Rx/blob/master/Receiver1.ino

I think I need to configure these parameters to get it working:

```
// Variables for Manchester Receiver Logic:
word    sDelay     = 250;  //Small Delay about 1/4 of bit duration  try like 250 to 500
word    lDelay     = 500;  //Long Delay about 1/2 of bit duration  try like 500 to 1000, 1/4 + 1/2 = 3/4
byte    polarity   = 0;    //0 for lo->hi==1 or 1 for hi->lo==1 for Polarity, sets tempBit at start
byte    tempBit    = 1;    //Reflects the required transition polarity
byte    discards   = 1;    //how many leading "bits" need to be dumped, usually just a zero if anything eg discards=1
byte    discNos    = 0;    //counter of how many discarded
boolean firstZero  = false;//has it processed the first zero yet?  This a "sync" bit.
boolean noErrors   = true; //flags if signal does not follow Manchester conventions
//variables for Header detection
byte    headerBits = 10;   //The number of ones expected to make a valid header
byte    headerHits = 0;    //Counts the number of "1"s to determine a header
//Variables for Byte storage
byte    dataByte   = 0;    //Accumulates the bit information
byte    nosBits    = 0;    //Counts to 8 bits within a dataByte
byte    maxBytes   = 9;    //Set the bytes collected after each header. NB if set too high, any end noise will cause an error
byte    nosBytes   = 0;    //Counter stays within 0 -> maxBytes
//Variables for multiple packets
byte    bank       = 0;    //Points to the array of 0 to 3 banks of results from up to 4 last data downloads 
byte    nosRepeats = 0;    //Number of times the header/data is fetched at least once or up to 4 times
//Banks for multiple packets if required (at least one will be needed)
byte  manchester[4][20];   //Stores 4 banks of manchester pattern decoded on the fly
```

Comment: How do you know that the hardware is working? OOK isn't very reliable and broadband signals will be a pain to use on the 433MHz bands. What does the radio signal look like, what does the digital data on the receiver side look like?

Comment: It successfully decode my WH1080 weather station. The code I use can decode another OOK temp/humidity sensor.